# Python replacing numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, random, list-comprehension

Hi I have a list of numbers with some 'None''s in them that I want to replace with other numbers in the list that are not 'None'.

For example, for the list below:

```
listP = [ 2.5,  3,  4, None, 4, 8.5, None, 7.3]
```

I want the two `None` items to be replaced with random numbers in the list that are not themselves a `None`. So in this example the None could be replaced by 2.5 or 3 or 4 or 8.5 or 7.3.

Is there anyway to do this in one line of code?

Comment: Your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11505354) was a radical change, where you made my O(N) solution a O(N^2) one, because now you recalculate the `numbers` list *for each iteration*. Not a good idea! For each number added to the list, you exponentially increase the amount of work done; 2 numbers takes 4 steps, 10 numbers 100 steps, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use two steps; extract the non-None values for `random.choice()` to pick from, then use a list comprehension to actually pick the random values:

```
import random

numbers = [n for n in listP if n is not None]
result = [n if n is not None else random.choice(numbers) for n in listP]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter` the list first to construct a list of not-`None` values and then randomly choose from it using `choice`:

```
import random

listP = [ 2.5,  3,  4, None, 4, 8.5, None, 7.3]
listR = filter(lambda x: x is not None, listP)
print([l if l is not None else random.choice(listR) for l in listP])
```

result:

```
[2.5, 3, 4, 7.3, 4, 8.5, 4, 7.3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehensions

`>>> [x if x else 'WHATEVER' for x in [ 2.5,  3,  4, None, 4, 8.5, None, 7.3]]
[2.5, 3, 4, 'WHATEVER', 4, 8.5, 'WHATEVER', 7.2999999999999998]`

Comment: This only answers half of the question.

Comment: There is actually 2 questions and I'm answering the one that is in the title.

I believe it's better to learn general concepts, not to get an answer to a your specific issue.

And it's better to ask questions as limited in scope as possible.

Comment: The title does not contain a question at all, and if it does, you are not answering it either (you are replacing Nones, whereas the title "asks" how to replace numbers). I can see exactly one question: "How to replace None with random numbers from the list". This may require multiple steps, but that does not make it multiple question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
import random

listP = [2.5,  3,  4, None, 4, 8.5, None, 7.3]
numbers = [num for num in listP if num is not None]
answer = [el if el is not None else random.choice(numbers) for el in listP]
print(answer)
```

**Sample Output**

```
[2.5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 8.5, 8.5, 7.3]
```

This creates a `numbers` list by filtering out the `None` values from `listP`. It then uses a list comprehension with `random.choice()` to fill `None` values with a random choice from `numbers`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Get any value from a list except `None`. I use `max` function to get this.
2. Check max value is not `None`
3. Use list comprehension to create new list which replace `None` value with max value.

**Demo**:

```
>>> listP = [ 2.5,  3,  4, None, 4, 8.5, None, 7.3]
>>> l_max = max(listP)
>>> if l_max:
...     listP = [n if n is not None else max(listP) for n in listP]
... 
>>> listP
[2.5, 3, 4, 8.5, 4, 8.5, 8.5, 7.3]
>>>
```

1. [**`max`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) is inbuilt function.
2. [**`List Comprehension`**](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that with "random number" OP did not mean "any [random number](https://www.xkcd.com/221/) you like" but actually a random number from that list, selected randomly each time.

Comment: @tobias_k yes, others are given answer by using `random number`. question is that replace `None` with any random value from the list, So we can pick any value from a list (other than `None`). I pick maximum value from the list.